# C# - Visual Studio - Use different Design Views for Solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, frontend, design-view

We have 2 customers using the same software but the frontend should look differently for each customer.

Is it possible for C# applications (Visual Studio 2017) to just design 2 different frontend design views and differentiate the views with a simple if / else statement at the beginning of the program?

Comment: It's not included as a keword of your post, but if you are using MVC, it can be accomplished simply usign different layouts. I've made this in the past, to allow having 2 different site templates (both based in bootstrap) that could be switched in runtime by user interaction. If this results useful for your case, I could provide you some code as a walkthrough.

Comment: @beinando, If your app is very large, I don't suggest that you did it. If your program is small, I recommend that you can add controls and events in the form_load and page_load event to use if and else to set different design views.